# How should I understand the $\sigma$-algebra in Kolmogorov's zero-one law?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm learning [Kolmogorov's zero-one law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero-one_law) in probability theory:

> Let $(Ω,{\mathcal F},P)$ be a probability space and let $F_n$ be a sequence of mutually independent $\sigma$-algebras contained in $\mathcal{F}$. Let
>       $$G_n=\sigma\bigg(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty F_k\bigg)$$
>   be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $F_n, F_{n+1}, \dots$. Then Kolmogorov's zero-one law asserts that for any event
>   $$ F\in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G_n$$
>   one has either $P(F) = 0$ or $1$.

I've no idea how $G_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} G_n$ would look like. What's the point of such construction? Could any one come up with some concrete examples of how this theorem works?

Comment: Small question, how do we know that $\sigma(\cup_{k=n}^\infty F_k)$ is "the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $F_n,F_{n+1},...$"? For example, $\sigma(A\cup B)$ is not the smallest $\sigma$ algebra containing $A,B$, is it?

Comment: @BlueBuck: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#.CF.83-algebras_generated_by_families_of_sets

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how that article answers my question. I understand what the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a family (such as $F_n,F_{n+1},...$) means, I just don't understand why the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the union of sets in that family gives the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the family.

Comment: @BlueBuck I think: 1 The smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A,B$ is $\sigma(A,B) := \sigma(\sigma(A) \cup \sigma(B))$, if $A$ and $B$ are events. 2 $\sigma(A,B) = \sigma(A \cup B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are $\sigma$-algebras

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The usual name for the sigma algebra you have there is the "tail" $\sigma-$algebra.  It is all the stuff that does not depend on finitely many of the $\sigma-$ algebras.

I usually think about the Kolmogorov 0-1 law like this: if you have a sequence of independent random variables and an event that is invariant if you ignore finitely many of the variables, then the probability of that event is either 0 or 1.

A typical example of how you can actually use this is to show that the convergence in the classical central limit theorem cannot be almost sure.

Let $X_i$ be a sequence of $iid$ random variables with $EX_i = 0$ and $EX_i^2 = 1$ and let $$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

It is easy to see that for any fixed $n$ and $M>0$ the event $$\{ \limsup_k \frac{S_k}{\sqrt{k}} >M\}$$ lies in $$\sigma(\cup_{k=n}^\infty F_k)$$ since it only depends on the "tail" of our sequence (this is clear if you write out the definition of $\limsup$).  Therefore by independence, the probability of this event is either 0 or 1.  Using the central limit theorem, it is not hard to see that this is probability is positive for any fixed $M$ and therefore it is $1$. We then obtain that $$P(\limsup \frac{S_k}{\sqrt{k}} = \infty) = 1$$

Symmetry gives that $$P(\liminf \frac{S_k}{\sqrt{k}} = - \infty) = 1$$ so we cannot have almost sure convergence (or convergence in probability).

Comment: can you explain how you got that probability is positive using Central limit theorem? I'm new to this topic.

Comment: You wrote: "It is easy to see that for any fixed $n$ and $M>0$ the event $$\{ \limsup_k \frac{S_k}{\sqrt{k}} >M\}$$ lies in $$\sigma(\cup_{k=n}^\infty F_k)$$ since it only depends on the 'tail' of our sequence (this is clear if you write out the definition of lim sup)". As is customary when the phrase "It is easy to see that..." is used in mathematical writing, the following statement is either false or so difficult that the author was unable to actually provide a proof (likewise "it is clear that..."). I, for one, do not see why the statement should be true. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @SahibaArora For each $\omega$, $1_{\{\limsup \frac{S_k}{\sqrt{k}} > M\}}(\omega)  = \limsup_{k \to \infty} 1_{\{\frac{S_k}{\sqrt{k}} > M\}} (\omega)$. We have $ 0 \leq 1_{\{\frac{S_k}{\sqrt{k}} > M\}} \leq 1$ and the function $1$ is integrable. Apply the version of Fatou's lemma for limsup and note $P(\frac{S_k}{\sqrt{k}} > M)$ converges to a positive number.

Comment: @EvanAad I don't check this often, so I deleted my previous comment and just wrote out the details. Sorry if you got two notifications for this. Note that for fixed $n$, $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{k}} = 0$. You can check that if you have two sequences $a_k,b_k$ and $a_k \to 0$, then $\limsup_{k \to \infty} (a_k + b_k) = \limsup b_k$ ($\leq$ is free, then take a subsequence along which $b_{k_j} \to \limsup_k b_k$ for the reverse inequality). It follows that pointwise, $\limsup_k \sqrt{k}^{-1} \sum_{j=1}^{k} X_j = \limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt{k}^{-1} \sum_{j=n+1}^k X_j$.

Comment: $F_k = \sigma(X_k)$ here. It then suffices to show that $\limsup \sqrt{k}^{-1} \sum_{j=n+1}^k X_j$ is $\sigma(\cup_{j=n}^\infty F_j)$ measurable. Note that $\sqrt{k}^{-1} \sum_{j=n+1}^k X_j$ is $\sigma(\cup_{j=n}^\infty F_j)$ measurable for each $k\geq n+1$. Then $\sup_{i \geq k} \sqrt{i}^{-1} \sum_{j=n+1}^i X_j$ is measurable for each $k\geq n+1$ and thus $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sup_{i \geq k} \sqrt{i}^{-1} \sum_{j=n+1}^i X_j = \limsup_k \sqrt{k}^{-1} \sum_{j=n+1}^k X_j$ is measurable. The last step is $\limsup f_k(\omega) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \sup_{i \geq k}f_i(\omega)$.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Possible issue: the zero-one law assumes that the sequence is comprised of *independent* random variables, but surely the scaled partial sums $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ are *not* independent of one another. In fact, using your logic, you could prove a sequence of identical random variables could not converge almost surely to itself by looking at the event {X>M}. Am I misunderstanding how you applied the zero-one law?

Comment: @rem Yes, see my response to the other question in these comments. The tail sigma algebra is the one for the i.i.d. sequence of Xs.

Answer (score 12):

Even though the tail-$\sigma$-algebra is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$, it can be in some sense much more complex. In particular, the tail-$\sigma$-algebra may not countably generated even in the most well-behaved cases. This implies that there cannot be any (real-valued) random variable representing the informational content of the tail-$\sigma$-algebra in general.

An *atom* in a $\sigma$-algebra is a nonempty measurable set with no nonempty measurable proper subset. A measurable space is *atomic* if every point is contained in some atom (the atoms form a cover).

**Lemma:** If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is countably generated, then it is atomic. If there is a $0-1$-valued measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, then there exists an atom $A$ such that $\mu(A)=1$.

**Proof (Sketch):** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a countable family such that $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{F}$. We can assume without loss of generality that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under complements. Then for each $\omega\in\Omega$, the set $A(\omega)=\bigcap\{A\ni\omega:A\in\mathcal{C}\}$ is measurable and the atom containing $\omega$. Now if $\mu$ is $0-1$-valued, the for each $A\in\mathcal{C}$ either $\mu (A)=1$ or $\mu (A^C)=1$. The intersection of all measure one events in $\mathcal{C}$ is an atom with measure one.

**Corollary:** The tail-$\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega=\{0,1\}^\infty$ is not countably generated.

**Proof:** Endowe the space with the fair coin-flipping measure. Let $\omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\ldots\}$ be any element in $\Omega$. Let $A_\omega^n$ be the set of all sequences in $\Omega$ that coincide with $\omega$ in all coordinates except for, maybe, the first $n$ coordinates. Clearly, $A_\omega^n$ is countable and so is $B_\omega=\bigcup_n A_\omega^n$. So $\mu (B_\omega)=0$. Also, $B_\omega$ is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra. But since $\omega$ was arbitrary, this shows that every atom would have measure zero. By the Lemma, the tail-$\sigma$-algebra is not countably generated.

The argument is taken from *Borel Spaces* by Rao and Rao (1981).

Comment: May I know how you define "atomic" here? Thanks

Comment: @Theta30 It's defined above: "An *atom* in a $\sigma$-algebra is a nonempty measurable set with no nonempty measurable proper subset."

Comment: I refer to "atomic" as used in Lemma.

Comment: @Theta30 Oh, sorry- Iedited it now. *Atomic* means that every point lies in some atom.

Comment: Dumb question: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: You wrote (in the end of the Corollary's proof): "But since $\omega$ was arbitrary, this shows that every atom would have measure zero." I don't see why this should be the case. Would you mind explaining please?

Comment: @EvanAad By Kolmogorov's 0-1-law, every set in the tail-$\sigma$-algebra has probability $0$ and $1$. If the tail $\sigma$-algebra where countably generated, then there would exist some atom, a minimal nonempty tail-measurable set, with measure $1$. But there can be no minimal nonempty tail-measurable set of measure $1$, since every element is contained in a tail-measurable set of measure $0$.

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't answer my question. It is precisely the claim that "every element is contained in a tail-measurable set of measure $0$" that I don't understand. I mean, I understand that every $\omega$ is contained in a tail-measurable set of measure $0$, but why does it mean that every atom of the tail $\sigma$-algebra is contained in such a set?

Comment: @EvanAad Let $\mu$ be the involved measure, which is $0-1$-valued on the tail-$\sigma$-algebra. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that the tail-$\sigma$-algebra is countably generated. By the Lemma,there exists an atom $A$ in the $\sigma$-algebra such that $\mu(A)=1$. Pick some $\omega\in A$.

Comment: We know there is a set $B_\omega$ that contains $\omega$, is measurable in the tail-$\sigma$-algebra, and has $\mu$-measure $0$. A subset of a measure zero set has 
measure zero, so $B_\omega\cap A\neq A$. Therefore, $A\cap B_\omega$ is a proper subset of $A$ measurable in the tail-$\sigma$-algebra. It is also clearly nonempty, since $\omega\in A\cap B_\omega$. This contradicts $A$ being an atom.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks!