# How do Kolmogorov 0-1 law and CLT imply normalized sample mean doesn't converge in probability nor a.s.?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

From [WIkipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm)

> the central limit theorem states that the sums Sn scaled by the
>   factor $1/\sqrt{n}$ converge in distribution to a standard normal
>   distribution. Combined with Kolmogorov's zero-one law, this implies
>   that these quantities converge neither in probability nor almost
>   surely: $$
>      \frac{S_n}{\sqrt n} \ \stackrel{p}{\nrightarrow}\ \forall, \qquad \frac{S_n}{\sqrt n} \ \stackrel{a.s.}{\nrightarrow}\ \forall, \qquad
>  \text{as}\ \ n\to\infty. $$

How do Kolmogorov 0-1 law and CLT imply normalized sample mean doesn't converge in probability nor a.s.?

Thanks!

Comment: I wrote up the argument here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210131/how-should-i-understand-the-sigma-algebra-in-kolmogorovs-zero-one-law/210152#210152