# Step in a proof in a probability exercise

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I'm working through the same book as in this question [Limit superior of $\sum_{j=1}^n X_j$ with $\mathbf{P}[X_j = 1] = \mathbf{P}[X_j = -1] = 0.5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115270/limit-superior-of-sum-j-1n-x-j-with-mathbfpx-j-1-mathbfpx-j?lq=1), and the top voted answer has a step in the solution that I'm misunderstanding.

The author claims "Fix $N$. Remark that if there is a sequence of $2N+1$ elements of $(X_n)$ which have the same sign, then the sequence cannot belong to $C_N$."

What if we took $N = 2$ and considered $1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 - 1 - 1 -1 -1 = 0$. Then $+1$ and $-1$ occur $2N+1=5$ times, but this event is in $C_2$. I feel like I'm really fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's stick with the case $N=2$, hopefully everything will be clear once that's sorted.

As I read it, $C_2$ is the set of all series of terms $\pm1$ such that every partial sum is from $-2$ to $2$, and the claim is that there cannot be $5$ terms of $+1$ in a row, or $5$ terms of $-1$ in a row.

Suppose there are $5$ terms of $+1$ in a row.  Then the series looks something like
$$\cdots+1+1+1+1+1+\cdots\ .$$
Now if the sequence were to be in $C_2$, then the sum encompassing the first set of dots in the above expression would have to be $-2,-1,0,1$ or $2$.  But then after adding the five $1$s you would get $3,4,5,6$ or $7$.  So this series cannot be in $C_2$.  Similar argument if you have $-1$ five times in a row.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should stop trying to learn math so late in the evening. Thank you!