# Doubt on Tail events and Kolmogorov Zero-One Law

Tags: probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

In [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) on the law of the iterated logarithm, one states that, given $M>0$, the event 
$$A=\left\{\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} > M\right\}$$
has probability $0$ or $1$ by Kolmogorov Zero One Law. This leads me to believe that $A$ is a tail event.

While trying to show that $A$ is a tail event, I observed that $S_n$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n \mathcal{F}_k\right)$ where $\mathcal{F_k} = \sigma(X_k)$. Even though the random variables $X_n$ are independent, the random variables $S_n$ are not. So how does one show that $A$ is a tail event?

I looked at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/210152/35983), but I think that there is a jump where they say that $A$ is in $\sigma\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=n}^\infty \mathcal{F}_k\right)$.

Kindly help me in understanding how to go about this problem. Hints and tips as always are appreciated.

Comment: For every fixed $N$, $$\left\{\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} > M\right\}=\left\{\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n-S_N}{\sqrt{n}} > M\right\}\in\sigma((X_n)_{n>N}).$$

Comment: Thanks Did. If you write that as an answer, I'll be able to credit you.

Answer (score 5):

Credit to Did for this:

$$\left\{ \limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} > M \right\}= \left\{ \limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{S_n-S_m}{\sqrt{n}} > M \right\}$$
for every $m \geq 1$.

Now $$\left\{\frac{S_n-S_m}{\sqrt{n}} > M\right\} \in \sigma\left(\bigcup_{k=m}^n \mathcal{F_k}\right)$$
and
 $$\left\{\limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{S_n-S_m}{\sqrt{n}} > M\right\} \in \sigma\left(\bigcup_{k=m}^\infty \mathcal{F_k}\right)$$
Since this is true for every $m$, we have
$$\left\{ \limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} > M \right\} \in \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty\sigma\left(\bigcup_{k=m}^\infty \mathcal{F_k}\right)$$

Thus it is a tail event.

**Update**: I'd like to point out that the source of my confusion was also from the [Hewitt Savage Zero One Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewitt%E2%80%93Savage_zero%E2%80%93one_law) article on Wikipedia which said that one could not apply Kolmogorov Zero One Law to $S_n$ as the events were not independent. However they were talking about a specific subsequence and not the $\limsup$ subsequence.