# Prove divergence of a series with the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf, central-limit-theorem

In Probability Theory by A. Klenke (3rd version), in the proof of Theorem 19.35 it is required to show that almost surely:

$$
R_W^+:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\exp\big(\sum_{k=0}^{n}X_k\big)=\infty
\\
R_W^-:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\exp\big(-\sum_{k=-n}^{1}X_k\big)=\infty
$$
where $X_k$, $k\in\mathcal{Z}$, are i.i.d. random variables with zero expectation and finite variance.

The given explanation is to use the **Central Limit Theorem to show that**
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}X_k>-\infty \quad(1)
\\
\limsup_{n\to\infty}-\sum_{k=-n}^{1}X_k>-\infty \quad(2)
$$

From this answer ([How should I understand the $\sigma$-algebra in Kolmogorov's zero-one law?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210131/how-should-i-understand-the-sigma-algebra-in-kolmogorovs-zero-one-law/210152#210152)) I am able to show that (1) holds.

**My questions mainly related to the strategy of the proof:**

1. Are we looking at (1) and (2) because they are related to the necessary condition of convergence of the series, that is the $n$-th term vanishes to zero?
2. Why the author uses the $\limsup$ and not $\liminf$? I usually struggle to understand when to use one or the other in proofs.
3. How can I show that (2) holds?

Let me know if more context is needed. Thanks for your help and suggestions.